# FTP server “Transfer Complete” not received by Client

Tags: linux, java, ftp

Using vsftpd 3.0.2 on ubuntu 14.04. Clients connecting via JavaApplet typically from Win7 using standard FTP. Issue occurs on both IE and FireFox. On small transfers clients do not have problems. On larger files some clients do not "hear" "Transfer Complete" and sit waiting to send the next file. They sit for 10 minutes then vsftpd issues a "421 Timeout."

The applet uploads 3 files, a xxxx.zip, xxxx.xml and xxxx.log.  The xxxx.zip gets fully uploaded but then it stalls and the .xml and .log never get uploaded.

The applet uses the same username / password so many connections from different users can be logged in at the same time with the same username/password combination.  The applet prevents a user from opening more than 1 applet at a time.

Other clients can submit 5GB files with no issues. Any ideas?

Vsftpd.log snippet:

```
Wed Jul  1 00:52:22 2015 [pid 42721] CONNECT: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:22 2015 [pid 42721] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "220 Welcome to CompanyName, Inc. FTP service."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:23 2015 [pid 42721] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "USER ftpusername"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:23 2015 [pid 42721] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "331 Please specify the password."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:23 2015 [pid 42721] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "PASS <password>"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:23 2015 [pid 42719] [ftpusername] OK LOGIN: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:23 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "230 Login successful."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:23 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "TYPE I"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:23 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "SIZE 202718.zip"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "550 Could not get file size."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "PWD"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "257 "/""
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "TYPE I"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "PASV"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,200,186)."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "SIZE 202718.zip"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:25 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "550 Could not get file size."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:26 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "REST 0"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:26 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "350 Restart position accepted (0)."
Wed Jul  1 00:52:26 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP command: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "STOR 202718.zip"
Wed Jul  1 00:52:26 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "150 Ok to send data."
Wed Jul  1 01:08:50 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] OK UPLOAD: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "/202718.zip", 508473359 bytes, 504.23Kbyte/sec
Wed Jul  1 01:08:50 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "226 Transfer complete."
Wed Jul  1 01:18:51 2015 [pid 42724] [ftpusername] FTP response: Client "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "421 Timeout."
```

Java Applet Log Snippet

```
creating heartbeat
Uploading: 202718.zip
Checking if file already exists on server and what size it is
ftp is NOT null
ftp is connected
UploadPage: FTP Command Sent: ---> SIZE 202718.zip
UploadPage: FTP Command Received: 550 Could not get file size.
UploadPage: FTP Command Sent: ---> PWD
Time to upload the file
UploadPage: FTP Command Received: 257 "/"
UploadPage: FTP Command Sent: ---> TYPE I
UploadPage: FTP Command Received: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
UploadPage: FTP Command Sent: ---> PASV
UploadPage: FTP Command Received: 227 Entering Passive Mode (172,26,157,245,200,186).
UploadPage: FTP Command Sent: ---> SIZE 202718.zip
UploadPage: FTP Command Received: 550 Could not get file size.
UploadPage: FTP Command Sent: ---> REST 0
UploadPage: FTP Command Received: 350 Restart position accepted (0).
UploadPage: FTP Command Sent: ---> STOR 202718.zip
UploadPage: FTP Command Received: 150 Ok to send data.
applet is being stopped
applet is being destroyed
```

The applet is being stopped / destroyed is from the user giving up and closing the web page containing the applet.
The process should have continued and uploaded the associated .xml and .log files.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically caused by a firewall/proxy or similar network component on the way between the client and the server.

During long transfers, there's no communication between the client and the server on an FTP control connection and the firewall (or similar) may decide to close the connection.

Check the firewall configuration, if you can set a longer "timeout" for (seemingly) idle connections.

Comment: I'm out of work till monday. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the guidance.  BTW WinSCP ROCKS! I use it every day all day.